# 'Adam' object has no attribute 'Adam'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, face-detection, adam

This is how I imported the modules

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, Activation
from keras.models import Model, Input
from keras import optimizer_v2
from keras.optimizer_v2 import adam
import keras.backend as K
```

But I'm getting this Error

[image: Error Message]

I tried using `adam = adam(learning_rate= 0.00001)` but it doesn't work either

Comment: `from keras.optimizers import Adam` then `opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.00001)`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following steps and it worked

```
import keras
adam = keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam(learning_rate= 0.00001)
deblur_CNN.compile(optimizer= adam, loss= 'mean_squared_error')
deblur_CNN.load_weights('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/FDmodels/deblur_cnn_weights.h5')
```

after specifying the exact path to the `adam.Adam` module it worked fine.
Still, if anyone wants to add something can add.